# Output everything after the first full stop in a paragraph in php

Tags: php, html, strpos

I have a header section on my site which outputs the title and the first sentence of a news article. Below I would like to output the rest of the article minus the first paragraph.

Something like this would be great:

```
// Full Article

$NewsArticle = "This is the article. I hope you like it.";

// Find the First Full stop

// Save everything after the first full stop to $NewsArticle 

$NewsArticle == "I hope you like it";
```

Any help on this would be great!

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Did you even try anything yet?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php plus http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php or explode if you do not need the last full stop either

Comment: Yes I've been trying strpos but had no luck. Thought I'd ask for some helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
substr($NewsArticle, strpos($NewsArticle, ".")+1)
```

Comment: Thanks, apologies for the novice question.

Comment: You are welcome. No need to apologize, we are novice in some ways, more importantly is to keep on learning and never afraid to ask when in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Just use substr function.

```
$str = "This is the article. Enjoy reading it. I hope you like it.";
$str_res = substr($str, strpos($str, ".")+1);
echo $str_res;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply - I really should have been more detailed with my problem, i need it to output everything after the first full stop, even if the second index of string contains a full stop, example:

$str = "This is the article. Enjoy reading it. I hope you like it.";

$str_res needs to output: "Enjoy reading it. I hope you like it."